# Enum-based singleton implementation and unit tests which preserve state as a side-effect of enum

Tags: java, junit, enums, singleton

As many would say, the singleton is bad, it is an "anti-pattern". Fortunately or not I work with some code which DOES have it and it would not go away in near future. So my problem is as follows.

A singleton having a state:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public enum Singleton {
    INSTANCE;

    private final Map<String, String> _mapper = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public String getValue(String key) {
        return _mapper.get(key);
    }

    public void addEntry(String key, String val) {
        _mapper.put(key, val);
    }

    public String removeKey(String key) {
        return _mapper.remove(key);
    }
}
```

Very dumb test which does not take into account that singleton INSTANCE state is preserved over test runs:

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

public class SingletonTest {

    public static final String KEY_1 = "key_1";

    @Test public void testOne() {
        Singleton.INSTANCE.addEntry(KEY_1, "val_1");
        Singleton.INSTANCE.addEntry("key_2", "val_2");
    }

    @Test public void testTwo() {
        Assert.assertNull(Singleton.INSTANCE.getValue(KEY_1));
    }
}
```

How the state could be cleaned in-between of test runs ? Could it be done with JUnit Runners ?

Actual state of object is more complicated and initialised via a constructor. I was looking for something like : http://powermock.googlecode.com/svn/docs/powermock-1.3.5/apidocs/org/powermock/core/classloader/annotations/PrepareForTest.html

Comment: If the member functions of Singleton that are context sensitive are few, you can try to use a `ThreadLocal` variable. If the variable is set, use the `ThreadLocal` context otherwise use the global context

Comment: I think you need to edit the question to be more precise about what kinds of solutions are and aren't acceptable, and why they're not. It's hard to guess around the constraints you don't seem to be telling us.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a method decorated with `@After` that will be executed after each test is executed. In this method, you can clear the state of the map in your enum:

```
@After
public void clear() {
    Singleton.INSTANCE.removeKey(KEY_1);
    Singleton.INSTANCE.removeKey("key_2");
    //and on and on...
}
```

Of course, a better approach would be having a `clear` method in your `enum` that will clear the values of the map, so the body of your `@After` method would become shorter:

```
@After
public void clear() {
    //assuming you can create such method
    Singleton.INSTANCE.clearEntries();
}
```

Comment: clear() would be one part of the story, because actual state is more complicated, what is there is only a snippet simple enough to reproduce my problem.

Comment: @ArtemOboturov post the real code to get a more accurate answer instead.

Comment: The real problem is : why should the state be cleared up between tests ? Suppose I would start a paraller runner, your approach will fail.

Comment: @ArtemOboturov you first ask how to clear the state between test runs, now you ask why should? Seriously, I still don't get your real exact problem. Also, if you start a parallel runner without using my approach, the tests should fail as well.

Comment: That's why I made an edit to push you to the classloader manipulation or some other technique which I probably do not know.

Comment: @ArtemOboturov my question for you is simple: do you want/need to maintain the state of the map in the enum after each test call or not?

Comment: Yes for the app. But No, for the tests. I do not consider the manual clean-up with @Before/@After as a solution.

Comment: @ArtemOboturov why do you not consider it as a solution? What's the exact problem with this approach you don't find it *good*?

Answer (score 1):

Here's something you may want to consider.

```
  enum Singleton {
    INSTANCE;

    ThreadLocal<Map<String, String>> context = new ThreadLocal<Map<String, String>>();
    private final Map<String, String> _mapper = new HashMap<String, String>();

    void createContext() {
      context.set(new HashMap<String, String>());
    }

    Map<String, String> getMapper() {
      Map<String, String> mapper;
      mapper = context.get();
      if (mapper==null) {
        mapper = _mapper;
      }
      return mapper;
    }

    public String getValue(String key) {
      return getMapper().get(key);
    }
    // ...
  }
```

In your test, you would call `INSTANCE.createContext()` during the setup.

If `createContext` is never called then the thread local variable is not created so the normal `_mapper` is used. Otherwise, the thread local variable will be retrieved and used instead.

Comment: So what do the test will test ? Two different implementation I suppose.

Comment: The implementation is the same except for the map. The implementation is exactly the same except for the how you retrieve the mapper. If you set a context, then INSTANCE will use that context but otherwise there are no changes.

Comment: You would be using a different map if you cleared it between tests anyways.

Comment: @ArtemOboturov In theory you could call INSTANCE.createContext() in your application's main thread and test exactly the same implementation but you would lose the lazy initialization property of the singleton.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to include a package-private `clear` method on the enum. That's not totally fool-proof, but that method would hopefully be simple enough that it'll be pretty bug-free. In your example, it'd just call `_mapper.clear()`.

Another option is to create a class `Delegate` with all the same methods as `Singleton`, and have `Singleton` just delegate to an instance of that class. Then, you test `Delegate` (*not* `Singleton`), instantiating a new one each time.

```
public enum Singleton {
    final Delegate delegate = new Delegate();

    public String getValue(String key) {
        return delegate.getValue(key);
    }

    // etc
}

class Delegate { // probably best as package-private
    private final Map<String, String> _mapper = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public String getValue(String key) {
        return _mapper.get(key);
    }

    // etc
}
```

This gives you a `Delegate` class with non-global state, which is easier to test. The global state in the `Singleton` class is the global `Delegate` instance it creates at the enum's classload time.

Of course, testing any class that uses `Singleton` is going to be trickier, but that doesn't seem to be your question.

Comment: clear() would be one part of the story, because actual state is more complicated, what is there is only a snippet simple enough to reproduce my problem.

Comment: I expanded on the second part of my answer, which sounds like it's probably the better option for you.

Comment: We are getting to Singleton instance holder pattern. And I know a workaround to clean state in that case.

Comment: Because there would be no use to have enum in the first place. I can just pick up the holder solution and use reflection to clean it all up. Or just to use a holder instance created per test case.

Comment: But I thought you don't _want_ the enum? I took from your question that you don't like the singletonness, but you're stuck with it (I'm guessing it's too much of a pain to rip out and pass to everyone who needs it?). If that's true, then what's wrong with a solution that gets rid of the enum for testing, but keeps it for legacy code?